# Removing all items from recyclerview at ONCE on firebase ui

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, firebaseui

I can delete one at a time in the recyclerview but trying to figure out how to delete the entire element at ONCE in the recyclerview when the finished button is clicked. this is my first time making use of this platform to ask question. Please can someone assist me on this code, i try so many times to remove all items at ONCE from the recyclerview in firebase UI and get error or no results at all. please how to fix this kind of issue and here is my code below. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4ZAX.jpg)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);


    mCartTotal = findViewById(R.id.TV_ShoppingCart_Total);
    mBtnFinish = findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout_Cart_Next_Address);
    mShopping_RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_shopping_cart);

    mShopping_RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
    mShopping_RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);


    mBtnFinish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        //Please what should i put in here
            
            Intent navigateShippingScreen = new Intent(CartActivity.this, ShippingAddressActivity.class);
            navigateShippingScreen.putExtra("Total Price", String.valueOf(overAllTotalPrice));
            startActivity(navigateShippingScreen);
            finish();
        }
    });

    readDataCart();

}

private void readDataCart() {
    FirebaseUser AppUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (AppUser != null) {
        USER_ID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        CART_PRODUCT = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

        Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("REGISTERED USERS").document(USER_ID)
                .collection("CART PRODUCT").orderBy("productTime", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);


        options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<PharmacyCart_DataModel>()
                .setQuery(query, PharmacyCart_DataModel.class)
                .build();

        myAdapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<PharmacyCart_DataModel, myViewHolderCart>(options) {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolderCart holder, int position, @NonNull PharmacyCart_DataModel model) {

                holder.mCartTitle.setText(model.getProductCartName());
                holder.mCartPrice.setText("RM" + model.getProductCartPrice());
                holder.mCartQuantity.setText(model.getProductCartQuantity());

                int oneTypeProductPrice = Integer.valueOf(model.getProductCartPrice()) * Integer.valueOf(model.getProductCartQuantity());
                overAllTotalPrice = overAllTotalPrice + oneTypeProductPrice;
                mCartTotal.setText("RM " + String.valueOf(overAllTotalPrice));

                holder.mDeleteProductCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        _deleteCartItemNow(holder);

                        int oneTypeProductPrice = Integer.valueOf(model.getProductCartPrice()) * Integer.valueOf(model.getProductCartQuantity());
                        overAllTotalPrice = overAllTotalPrice - oneTypeProductPrice;
                        mCartTotal.setText("RM " + String.valueOf(overAllTotalPrice));
                    }
                });


            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public myViewHolderCart onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_cart_product, parent, false);
                return new myViewHolderCart(v);
            }

        };
        mShopping_RecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
}


private void _deleteCartItemNow(myViewHolderCart holder) {
    _deleteCartItem(holder.getAdapterPosition());

}

private void _deleteCartItem(int position) {
    myAdapter.getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getReference().delete();
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    myAdapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    myAdapter.stopListening();

}
```

Comment: clear the list you set to recyclerView

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this article, [How to delete a record from Firestore on a RecylerView left/right swipe?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) or [How to delete multiple records from Firestore using RecyclerView multi-selection?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166) might help.

Comment: @Alex Mamo Thank you so much. I have resolved this issue.

Comment: @Himesh Perera Thank you